# Creating abstract wrapper iterator

Tags: c++, inheritance, iterator, polymorphism, abstract

say I have two types of matrices: reg and sparse.
I created an abstract father class "Matrix", and the two above inherit from "Matrix".
I want to create an abstract iterator, such that "MatrixIterator" is the father abstract class, and "RegMatrixIterator", "SparseMatrixIterator" inherit from it. all in all 6 classes.

RegMatrix holds a vector representation, and SparseMatrix holds a map which maps between pairs of indices and the value.

what is the best way to implement the iterators?

Comment: Why don't you not just use a std::vector<Matrix> and iterate over that?

Comment: because I implement both types myself

Comment: Iterators don't play well with polymorphism. see here http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html

Comment: You're leaving us to go write a ton of code, knowing you might turn around and say "oh yeah - that's the way I did it, but I want to know if there's something better".  Post your working code, and if you have a specific problem getting it working list exactly what's happening, what you expected/hoped to happen etc..

Comment: @MartinMeeser He doesn't want to iterate over many matrices, but over the elements of a matrix.

Comment: @Walter you're right, I just want to iterate over elements of a vector, and a map, with the same iterator which is implemented differently for both types

Comment: If you want *abstract* iterator, then you have to declare all requiered methods abstract. That's all. Include some code e.g. having all the classes and specific iterators you want to join in one (creating one abstract base). Minimal requiered compilable code ;)

Comment: AH now I see what the problem is. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An `iterator` is a generic mechanism abstracting the details of how the elements are actually stored. As generic object orientated programming (OOP) don't really work well together, iterators are not commonly implemented via OOP.

I don't know why you want to use OOP for you `Matrix`, i.e. whether you really want to use run-time polymorphism on matrices. If this is really important, then you will want polymorphic `Matrix::begin()` and `Matrix::end()` and hence the need for a polymorphic `Matrix::iterator`. Code using such matrices will look like

```
#include <Matrix.hpp>
void foo(Matrix const&m)
{
  for(a : m) { [...] }
}
```

But you will pay the price of a virtual function call (virtual table look-up) for every call to a polymorphic method of `Matrix::iterator`. If this is not performance critical, this type of design is okay, though unusual for iterators.

However, I would prefer the generic programming approach, whereby the two matrix types may be derived from a common base, but not for the purpose of run-time polymorphism. Then each type simply has its own iterator type and its own non-virtual `begin()` and `end()`. Code using such matrices will look like

```
#include <Matrix.hpp>
template<typename Matrix>
typename std::enable_if<is_Matrix<Matrix>::value>:: // is_Matrix defined in Matrix.hpp
type foo(Matrix const&m)
{
  for(x : m) { [...] }
}
```

Instead of SFINAE (`std::enable_if`) you may simply `static_assert()` the correct matrix type, though
then your function may be ambiguous with another `foo(some_arg)`.